# How to raise our own custom SQLExceptions?

Tags: exception

```
DECLARE  
   c_id customers.id%type := 8;  
   c_name  customers.name%type;  
   c_addr customers.address%type;  
BEGIN  
   SELECT  name, address INTO  c_name, c_addr  
   FROM customers  
   WHERE id = c_id;  
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Name: '||  c_name);  
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Address: ' || c_addr);  
EXCEPTION  
   WHEN no_data_found THEN  
      dbms_output.put_line('No such customer!');  
   WHEN others THEN  
      dbms_output.put_line('Error!');  
END;
```

After the execution of above code at SQL Prompt, it produces the following result:

```
No such customer!
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Here the exception is captured by the exception block

I tried handling inbuilt exception using exception block, I am expecting a way to raise my own custom SQLEXCEPTION